# How can i solve $\int_0^t \frac{(t-\tau)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\tau^{\alpha}}d\tau$,

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I want to find the value of the integral
$$\int_0^t \frac{(t-\tau)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\tau^{\alpha}}d\tau,$$

where $0<\alpha<1$. Using Mathematica I found the solution to be

$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\frac{\Gamma(1-\alpha)}{\Gamma(\frac{5}{2}-\alpha)}t^{\frac{3-2\alpha}{2}}.$$

**Question**: Could anyone please help me solve this problem or give me some hints? Please, I have no idea  as to how exactly I can find the value of the integral.

Best..

Comment: The use of both $\;t\,,\,\tau\;$ in the same mathematical expression makes things easily confusing. Perhaps you should think on changing one of these symbols in your question.

Comment: This is simply the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function). Just let $\tau=tx$, where the new limits for *x* are $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint.* After the change of variable $$u=\frac{\tau}{t}$$
use the [Euler beta integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function):
$$
B(a,b)=\int_{0}^{1}(1-u)^{a-1} u^{b-1}\,du  = \frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}.
$$